# Promoting MySQL replica to primary during failover

Tags: mysql, replication, failover

The MySQL primary fails and I'm trying to promote the replica to primary.
Following the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html), I've already:

1. disabled the failed primary server on all load balancers
2. waited for the primary server to complete all its transactions:

   Source has sent all binlog to replica; waiting for more updates
3. set the primary server as super R/O
4. dumped all InnoDB databases from the failed primary server as a precaution
5. stopped the IO_THREAD of the replica
6. waited for the replica to complete all its transactions:

   Replica_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
7. stopped the SQL_THREAD of the replica
8. reset the GTID execution history and the binary log of the replica

However, there are discrepancies between the failed primary and the new primary servers:

- **failed primary server status**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                           |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000073 |      197 |              |                  | c219365c-bd04-11ed-b1e2-525400003001:1-4620 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

- **new primary server status**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| binlog.000001 |      157 |              |                  |                   |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

We can see that the positions are different and that the new primary has no 'Executed_Gtid_Set'.
Either I missed something, or the doc is incomplete.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Was GTID enabled?

Comment: Of course, on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue lays within the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html):

> On the replica Replica 1 being promoted to become the source, issue `STOP REPLICA` and `RESET MASTER`.

should be instead:

> On the replica Replica 1 being promoted to become the source, issue `STOP REPLICA` and `RESET REPLICA ALL`.

I recreated both MySQL servers from scratch and applied the 7 steps from the first post and replaced the 8th one by:

8. Reset the replica with `RESET REPLICA ALL;`

**On the primary before the switchover**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                           |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000010 |  1380513 |              |                  | a4228b68-e5b8-11ed-ac40-525400003001:1-1615 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

**On the new primary (former replica) after the switchover**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                                                                       |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000010 |     6841 |              |                  | 61ab9e32-e5b9-11ed-b4aa-525400003002:1-511,
a4228b68-e5b8-11ed-ac40-525400003001:1-1615 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It looks fine, except for the position which may or may not be a problem.